# HTML - Creating an ID card using CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

I need to create an ID card, using information given to me by a user, using a form. I have created the form, I just want to know how to design the card (with an image) using CSS? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make a `div`, add some `span` and use `position: absolute;`

```
<div class="background">
  <span class="name">aaa</span>
  <span class="birth">bbb</span>
  <span class="location">ccc</span>
  <span class="size">ddd</span>
</div>

.background {position: relative; background-image: ABC;}
.name {position: absolute; left: XYZpx; top: ZXYpx;}
etc pp
```